# Is it possible to secured only controllers marked with Spring @Secured annotation

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I have several controllers and want to secure only one of them,
spend some time but haven't figure out proper solution.

How to do it via config ?

Controllers :

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/somepath")
public class UnsecController {
// code here
}

@Secured("ROLE_CUSTOM")
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/somepath2")
public class SecController {
// code here
}
```

Config:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(securedEnabled = true, prePostEnabled = true)
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        web.ignoring().antMatchers("/js/**", "/css/**", "/fonts/**", "/static", "/swagger-ui.html");
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http
            .csrf().disable()
            .antMatcher("/**")
            .addFilterBefore(authFilter(), BasicAuthenticationFilter.class)
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/health").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and().sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
    }

    @Bean
    public MacaroonsAuthFilter authFilter() {
        return new MacaroonsAuthFilter();
    }
}
```

**Edit:**

I have 50 controllers from 100 that I want to secure,
but dont want to write them in configuration manually

Comment: If you have only one controller, which is secured (with `@Secured`), you can permit all paths (`anyRequest().permitAll()`).

Answer (score 0):

Controllers are secured by configuring the`WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`. If you only want to secure one controller-method, you need to configure the HttpSecurity in that way, that it only matches this path. All other methods are excluded from security. Something as follows:

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
http
.authorizeRequests()
.antMatchers("/somepath").hasRole("CUSTOM")
.anyRequest().permitAll();
}
```

The `@Secured` annotation is normally used on service methods and not in the controller.